# Trouble creating unique ID as it is being overwritten each refresh

Tags: javascript, html

This function is called as a form submit, and further calls a new function for rendering the list of divs. After this is done the website is refreshed because of drag and drop functionality. The problem is that I cant seem to find a way to create an unique ID that persists through page refresh and isnt overwritten on page load because of ex: "let taskId = 0".

Any ideas? :)

```js
function createNewTask(event){
  if(document.querySelector("[name='description']").value === "") {
    alert("Cannot add empty task.");
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    let taskId = 0;
    const description = document.querySelector("[name='description']").value;
    const givenTo = document.querySelector("[name ='givenTo']").value;
    const createdByName = document.querySelector("[name = 'workerName']").value;
    const task = {taskId, description, givenTo, createdByName, section: 'task-section'};
    const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];
    taskId++;
    taskList.push(task);
    window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskList));
    // renderTaskList();
    renderStoredList();
    //Reload page after createNewTask to activate draggable
    location.reload();
  }  
}
```

Comment: `taskId++;` is useless, because it’s never used again in this scope. Every time the function is called, `let taskId = 0;` causes `taskId` to be set to `0` again. You should move this variable to an outer scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads). You’re already using `localStorage`, so why not save `taskId` there? Alternatively, infer it from `(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("taskList")) ?? []).slice(-1)[0]?.taskId` (or some variant compatible with older browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `length` to get the next `taskId`.

```js
function createNewTask(event){
    if(document.querySelector("[name='description']").value === ""){
        alert("Cannot add empty task.");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        const tasklist = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || []
        let taskId = tasklist.length;
        const description = document.querySelector("[name='description']").value;
        const givenTo = document.querySelector("[name ='givenTo']").value;
        const createdByName = document.querySelector("[name = 'workerName']").value;
        const task = {taskId, description, givenTo, createdByName, section: 'task-section'};
        taskList.push(task);
        window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskList));
        // renderTaskList();
        renderStoredList();
        //Reload page after createNewTask to activate draggable
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot add a comment yet, I'll post it here as an answer.
What I would do on my end to keep track of the `taskId` is to also store the latest `taskId` that was last used in my `localStorage`, that way, it would persist.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('lastTaskId', taskId);
```

And then simply take that each time the page loads.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What if you assign taskId based on previous length of the taskList:

```
const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];
let taskId = taskList.length
```